# A weird IP with ping: different from nsLookup IP: different from actual IP

Tags: ping, ipv6, ip-address, ipv4, nslookup

**On another PC**
Can Google remote desktop into AcerDragon. But when accessing it via network, it cannot be found.

```
C:\>ping acerdragon

Pinging acerdragon.home **[192.168.1.9]** with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.8: Destination host unreachable.
```

But can so access with actual local IP address.
**Why? How to fix this?**

```
C:\>ping **192.168.1.14**

Pinging 192.168.1.14 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from **192.168.1.14**: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
```

**On AcerDragon**
Your Local IP is: **192.168.1.14**
ISP: Verizon Communications Inc.

```
C:\>hostname
AcerDragon

C:\>ping acerdragon

Pinging AcerDragon [fe80::d153:e9cf:e4ed:65e1%14] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from **fe80::d153:e9cf:e4ed:65e1%14**: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::d153:e9cf:e4ed:65e1%14: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::d153:e9cf:e4ed:65e1%14: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::d153:e9cf:e4ed:65e1%14: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::d153:e9cf:e4ed:65e1%14:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\>nslookup acerdragon
Server:  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    acerdragon.home
Address:  **192.168.1.9**

C:\Users\longtt>hostname
AcerDragon

C:\>nslookup 192.168.1.14
Server:  Wireless_Broadband_Router.home
Address:  192.168.1.1

Name:    new-host-2.home
Address:  192.168.1.14


C:\>ping **192.168.1.14**

Pinging 192.168.1.14 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from **192.168.1.14**: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

`[fe80::d153:e9cf:e4ed:65e1%14]` ...ping........vs......nsLookup.... ** `192.168.1.9`.....nslookup.....vs .....actualLocal......... ** `192.168.1.14` – long4short

Comment: **[fe80::d153:e9cf:e4ed:65e1%14] **   ...ping........vs......nsLookup....           ** 192.168.1.9 **    .....nslookup.....vs .....actualLocal.........                           
 ** 192.168.1.14 **

Comment: Reboot your router.

Comment: Thanks Mike.                                                                                            
Have rebooted both PC's more than once, and have rebooted the immediate switch (with the 2 PC's connected): Will try the router, it's the gateway for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like DNS on your router is wrong. Update the firmware.

When you ping by hostname you are getting an IPv6 result. Add "-4" to limit ping to IPv4:

```
ping acerdragon -4
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a mixture of DNS and link-local name resolution. With link-local name resolution the hosts themselves respond to multicast query packets when the host name matches the name in the query. You need to make sure the host names (as returned with the command `hostname` on the local computer) match the name-ip mapping on the DNS server. Or, you could rely solely on link-local name resolution, which frees you from the burden of adminstering the DNS server.